# Hbase Map and Reduce on same table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Is it possible to map and reduce on same hbase table? For instance consider the wordcount example, I want to map each individual row of the column,reduce it and write the worcount instantly on the same row. Is it possible to do that? If yes what will be the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but I do see a risk of getting in an infinite loop.

So if you can do this then you must make sure that the range of keys you use as input do NOT overlap with the keys you produce as output.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends of method of map reduce you are using. If you [Bulk Load techniques](http://hbase.apache.org/bulk-loads.html)  it is pretty safe to  do this operation, because it first read all data from table and only when update it. This is good for massive update of table and in this case has better performance when standard map reduce that works directly with table.